# Wordpress (Woocommerce) Edit address logs me out

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I hope you can help.
I've installed Woocommerce for Wordpress and have the following problem.

When a user goes into the page to edit billing address it logs the user out - refreshing the page or saving the new address takes you back into the login screen.

I have no idea how to debug or fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Mark

Comment: The best way to debug this is to 1. Return to one of the default WordPress themes and 2. Deactivate any additional plugins (other than WooCommerce). If it is working then there start activating one by one your theme and then the plugins to find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much kat_indo.
Bizarrely undoing all the plugins and replacing them has fixed the issue. Not sure how though.

Comment: Sometimes when using several plugins errors like that might appear. I am glad I could help! I will post my answer below, so other people can also easily find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to debug this is to

1. Change to one of the default WordPress themes. If you are not using a default WordPress theme, deactivate and activate one of the default ones (i.e. Twenty Twelve)
2. Deactivate any additional plugins (other than WooCommerce).
3. If it is working that means there's a conflict with either the theme or with one (or more) of the other plugins you are using.
4. First, re-activate the theme you were using and check. If the error continues, then probably the theme is creating the problem.
5. If it works fine with the theme, move to the plugins. Start activating one at the time and test. See which plugin is causing the problem.